# Percentage Configuration parameter reference

Tags: api, google-analytics

When using the API parameter reference bounce rate from analytics it runs as a number, not as a percentage, which is the formate needed.

Using Add-ons for Google Sheets to creat a Google Analytics Reporting, when using ga: bounceRate, when running the report, the bounce rate appears as a round number and not as a percentage, how may I change that?

Thanks for your help.

Regards, 
L.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code, some example output, and what is wrong with the example output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on, after you run a report you can use Sheets to format a range of cells in the results. From the Sheet menus choose "Format" > "Number" > "Percent".

Then, every time you run that report, the add-on will remember the number format you've chosen so you don't have to manually set it every time.